# Is my builder design pattern thread-safe?

Tags: c#, builder

Coming from a Java background, I have to implement something in C#. The class is a domain object which is composed of multiple other domain objects. I don't like to have a constructor with 10 fields, so I thought of using the builder design pattern! Here is what I came up with:

```
public class MyDomainObject
{
  public DomainObject1 Obj1 { get; private set; }
  public DomainObject2 Obj2 { get; private set; }
  public DomainObject3 Obj3 { get; private set; }
  ...

  public class DomainObjectBuilder
  {       
    private MyDomainObject _domainObj = new MyDomainObject();

    public DomainObjectBuilder(DomainObject1 obj1)
    {
        _domainObj.Obj1 = obj1;
    }

    public DomainObjectBuilder withDomainObject2(DomainObject2 obj2)
    { 
        _domainObj.Obj2 = obj2; 
        return this;    
    }

    .....  

    public MyDomainObject Build()
    {
      // Construct and Return the MyDomainObject
    }
  }
}
```

Now is this implementation thread safe? When I instantiate my domain object the following way:

```
var myDomainObject = new DomainObjectBuilder(obj1)
                         .withDomainObject2(obj2)
                         .withDomainObject3(obj3).build();
```

What happens if the calls between `withDomainObject2` and `withDomainObject3` is handled by different threads?

Comment: When would you share a builder between multiple threads? That sounds very unusual to me. (I'd also strongly recommend following .NET naming conventions, btw.)

Comment: What's more, how do you imagine a situation where these two methods would have been called by different threads?

Comment: You can (?) design immutable builder. [Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467176.aspx) (not sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't come across any code that splits a builder on multiple threads. The simple answer given your requirements is simply (no it is not thread safe).

Consider this example using your `MyDomainObject` class:

```
private MyDomainObject _myObj;

    void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DomainObject1 obj1 = new DomainObject1();   
        _myObj = new MyDomainObject(obj1);

        Thread oThread1 = new Thread(ThreadProc1);
        oThread1.Start();

        Thread oThread2 = new Thread(ThreadProc2);
        oThread2.Start();

        MyDomainObject myObjFinal = _myObj.Build();

        DomainObject2 obj2 = myObjFinal.Obj2; //No guarantee that Obj2 is set or initialized
        DomainObject3 obj3 = myObjFinal.Obj3; //No guarantee that Obj3 is set or initialized

    }

    void ThreadProc1()
    {
        DomainObject2 obj2 = new DomainObject2();
        MyDomainObject myObjModified = _myObj.withDomainObject2(obj2);

        DomainObject3 objNew = _myObj.Obj3; //No guarantee that Obj3 is set or initialized

    }

    void ThreadProc2()
    {
        DomainObject3 obj3 = new DomainObject3();
        MyDomainObject myObjModified = _myObj.withDomainObject3(obj3);

        DomainObject2 objNew = _myObj.Obj2; //No guarantee that Obj2 is set or initialized
    }
```

As you can see there is no guarantee that any of the objects is initialized or set when called after `Build()` in the main thread. The same applies when trying to access an object that is initialized in a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a constructor wit too many things.... the thing that you may not call some of these method, mean some of them are optional, i see that also i java, but here after some reversion of .NET framework, you can do it more simple... like this:

```
A a = new A(Required properties){
    Name="x",
    Family="Y",
    OpetionalProperty3 = "z",
    .......
};
```

and if you do not have any thing required, you can remove the parentheses at all( when you define optional properties).

```
A a = new A{
    Name="x",
    Family="Y",
    OpetionalProperty3 = "z",
    .......
};
```

---

And about your case and thread handeling, check out the 'volatile' syntax for variables - it ensure last value is in the field on every thread call